# DropdownButtonFormField call with class can't assign chosen value after method call

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to work on a project and I am fairly new to Flutter.

I have this `DropdownButtonFormField<ClassNoSearch>` and `value` is `_currentClassNoSearch` that is an object `ClassNoSearch _currentClassNoSearch;`

After I choose an item from this list,  `_getData();` function is called and it sets the `_currentClassNoSearch;` to null.

I don't want this to happen, instead, I want the chosen value to be the same after `_getData()`; but I can't seem to delete the `_currentClassNoSearch = null;` line.

`DropdownButtonFormField<ClassNoSearch>` :

```
DropdownButtonFormField<ClassNoSearch>(
                      hint: Text("Hint"),
                      isExpanded: true,
                      value: _currentClassNoSearch,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                      ),
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                      ),
                      onChanged: (ClassNoSearch newVal) {
                        setState(() {
                          _currentClassNoSearch = newVal;
                        });
                        _getData();
                      },
```

`_getData();`

```
  Future<HomeworkSudo> _getData() {
    if (_currentClassNoSearch == null) {
      return getHomeworkSudo("").then((HomeworkSudo result) {
        setState(() {
          activeHomeworkList = result.activeHomeWork;
          inactiveHomeworkList = result.passivHomeWork;
          classNoList = result.classNo;
        });
        return result;
      });
    } else {
      return getHomeworkSudo(_currentClassNoSearch.userClassDepartmentId)
          .then((HomeworkSudo result) {
        setState(() {
          _currentClassNoSearch = null;
          activeHomeworkList = result.activeHomeWork;
          inactiveHomeworkList = result.passivHomeWork;
          classNoList = result.classNo;
        });
        return result;
      });
    }
  }
```

As you can see If I delete the line that sets `_currentClassNoSearch = null;` i get the error below . Any ideas on how I should approach this?

> items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null
> Either zero or 2 or more DropdownMenuItems were detected with the same value.

[image]

Comment: Hi, in order to get better answers faster, please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example, basically a version of the problematic code that doesn't have extra details like `TextStyle` and depend on other app-specific variables and types, like `ClassNoSearch` and `HomeworkSudo`. Replace them with built-in types like `int` or `String` and make a self-contained version of the code to post. The goal is that people looking to help can run your code and debug it directly. Also, in the process of simplifying your code, you may find the cause of the error yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The code says the following assertion failed:

```dart
items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null
```

You don't include `items` in your code, so `items` is set to null by default, which is why the assertion fails.

Comment: Hi Levi. That assertion fails when I try to remove _currentClassNoSearch = null; line from _getData(); method which executes after DropdownButtonFormField. If I don't delete it, app works but not as intended. I want to assign _currentClassNoSearch the value user chooses from DropdownButtonFormField and I can't seem to make it happen.

Comment: Then it seems you may have cut off the part of your code where you include the `items` parameter -- make sure you post that. It looks like whatever you pass in to `items` depends on `_currentClassNoSearch` and that's what's causing the error.